# How to connect numpy and matplotlib to python 2.7.10 on windows XP (32bit)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I downloaded python 2.7.10
I downloaded numpy (matching version)
I downloaded matplotlib (matching version)

i runned them,they got installed, they even found the python 2.7.

then I started a project in python (pycharm) and wrote in:
import numpy as np

I got an error:
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

what to do now?

(Please if you could give me an answer as if you would explaining it to a toddler, because I saw a Linux first time a week ago :) )

Comment: Are you sure PyCharm is pointing to your newly installed python?  https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html

Comment: Thank you :) it solved the problem